# I'm getting this error using Java Mail API

Tags: java

```
Sun Nov 13 16:20:41 PKT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at SentItems.initialize(SentItems.java:229)
    at SentItems.<init>(SentItems.java:111)
    at SentItems$1.run(SentItems.java:98)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

I know why it is, it is due to turn off Google setting less secure app but I want to do this by Java code.

Comment: Can you add the email connection code of your program , of course masking things like IP, email ID, password etc.

Comment: Probably you should use SSL Authentication.Paste your code and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Read {
public static void check(String host, String storeType, String username,
String password)
{
try {
// create properties field
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("mail.imaps.host", host);
properties.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
properties.put("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
// Setup authentication, get session
Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
     return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
     }
     });
      emailSession.setDebug(true);
     // create the IMAP store object and connect with the IMAP server
     Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
     store.connect();
     // create the folder object and open it
     Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
     emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
     // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
     Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
     System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
     for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
     Message message = messages[i];
     System.out.println("---------------------------------");
     System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
     System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
     System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
     System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
     }
     // close the store and folder objects
     emailFolder.close(false);
     store.close();
     } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (MessagingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String host = "imap.gmail.com";// change accordingly
     String mailStoreType = "imap";
     String username = "*******@gmail.com";// change accordingly
     String password = "********";// change accordingly
     check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
     }
    }
```

Here is my code.